# Гарантирует ли .NET при Select().ToList(), что порядок элементов не изменится?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть `List<SomeObject>`, где `SomeObject`- это какой-то объект с десятком полей.

И есть какой-то метод, который принимает простой список значений string.

=> я делаю data.Select(x=>x.Item2).ToList()

Вопрос в том, что гарантируется ли при создании нового списка, что порядок элементов не поменяется?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380399/order-of-items-after-using-linq-select-extension-method если верить этому, то гарантируется.

Comment: [`Select`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,0bf6a998e9106ebc) возвращает итератор, в [реализации для списка](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d3661cf752ff3f44), это просто проход с увеличением индекса

Comment: Если `data` — это `myList.AsParallel()`, то не гарантируется

Comment: Если говорить общими словами, то List - список не сортированный, потому он не гарантирует никакого порядка обхода. Когда вы обходите список, вы можете только быть уверены в том, что вы пройдете все элементы. В каком порядке - это контракт или документация списка не поясняет. То, что вы обходите список в порядке добавления элементов - это не контракт списка, а, скорее, деталь реализации. Если вам нужен определенный порядок, то сортируйте ваши данные.

Comment: @tym32167 он не сортированный, но он упорядоченный - там вполне определены first/last элементы, индексы для каждого элепемента, результат GetEnumerator явно описан как энумератор, который пройдет от first до last, а не просто выдаст все элементы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `ToList` [гарантируется косвенно, через упоминание](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) копирования результатов

> You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached copy of the query results.

Copy явно подразумевает полную копию, включая порядок элементов последовательности.

Для `Select` гарантии в документации нет, но на практике он сохраняет порядок, и смена поведения поломает такое количество приложений, что смену порядка никто никогда вводить не будет.